# Conditional probability basic question

Tags: probability, statistics

3 Brothers named A,B,C are calling a radiohost.The probability of A calling radio
suscesfully is %48 ,B's %34 ,C's %18.And even if they reach the host , possiblity of host reading their messages; A-%14 ,B-%8,C%2.If we know host read messages of one of that brothers , what is the probability of the message reading is brother A's.
$$
P(A|B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B) = 0.48 * 0.14/ 0.22 
$$
Is that logic correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE! Please use [LaTeX](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to format mathematics notation in your questions.

Comment: I wish users would not downvote new users, just on the basis not using mathjax.  (@JacobErrington  mathjax $\neq$ LaTeX. They share a lot in common, but it is unreasonable to expect a new user to know how to format mathematics when they first post a question.  The asker has clearly attempted to answer the question, and is asking whether the logic she/he used is correct.

Comment: @amWhy I do agree.

Comment: Sorry for the format, i know you are totally right but i wasn't familiar with LaTex format. I will try to convert question to LaTex notation. Give me some time :D

Comment: Who said anything about downvoting? I agree that downvoting a new user solely based on formatting should be discouraged, and I did not not downvote the OP. All I did was point them at a reference for properly formatting their question.
@amWhy Also, I'm aware that MathJax-the-software and LaTeX-the-software are indeed not the same thing. I'm talking about LaTeX the notation. After all, the section heading on the page I linked says "LaTeX".

Comment: I edited the post.Can you guys check again?I think it is in correct format now

Comment: I'm sorry, @Jacob I did not mean to imply that you, yourself, downvoted the question because of its formatting.  I just don't really like to see the first comment below a new asker's post harking on "formatting." It would have been great to have expressed your welcome, as you did.  And at most suggest "in the future, it would help if you learned how to format your posts, as best as you can, as you're learning it.....

Comment: That's a great help, @user3524633!

Comment: Thank you all of you guys for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability of A calling the radiohost: $P(A)=48%$; $P(B)=34%$; $P(C)=18%$;
Probability that host will read messages is $P\left(\frac{A}{H}\right)=14%$;  $P\left(\frac{B}{H}\right)=8%$;  $P\left(\frac{C}{H}\right)=2%$

Now you have to find probability that the message he reads is of A therefore the formula you must use is:
$$P\left(\frac{H}{A}\right)= \frac{P\left(\frac{A}{H}\right) \cdot P(A)}{P \left(\frac{A}{H}\right)\cdot P(A)+P\left(\frac{B}{H}\right) \cdot P(B)+P\left(\frac{C}{H}\right) \cdot P(C)}$$

Now just substitute the values

Comment: Nice, helpful answer, Iti Shree!

Comment: Thank you.When i checked your formula it made much more sense than mine even at first glance.

Comment: You're welcome @user3524633

Comment: Hey..Nice answer +1, I just wanted to tell you that you can use double dollar i.e. `$$` to trigger the displaymode, this makes your answer look beautiful. Also, you can use `\rleft(` and `\right)` for brackets to adjust there size according to their content.

Comment: Thank you @JaideepKhare I'm really looking forward to know more about LeTex.

Comment: I have edited as I said.You can see the difference. For more information See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks friend, that shall help :)